# How to create Postgres database containing dot in it's name?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create the Postgres database using the terminal,

Normally we can create the database like

`CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;`

but I wanted to create with the database with a dot. like

`CREATE DATABASE my.database;`

I was trying to escape the characters. but it doesn't work

`CREATE DATABASE my.\database;`

`CREATE DATABASE my\.database;`

as an expected output, it should create the database named `my.database`

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE "my.database";`. But since `.` is used as seperator for schemas, tables, columns etc. this will probably lead to problems down the road.

Comment: *"How to create Postgres database containing dot in it's name?"* indeed @madflow sounds like trouble as it looks like the topicstarter is trying to emulate namespaces from Java or something like that ...`CREATE DATABASE "com.domain.type"`, `CREATE DATABASE "com.domain.type.sub_type"`.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should create the database using

`create database "my.database";`

Comment: Should be followed by "but don't because it's a terrible idea".

Comment: @404 with the why it is a terrible one.

Comment: @ntdash Because the `.` is used to separate the table name from schema, or column from table. For example, `SELECT * FROM schema1.table1` or `SELECT a.id, b.val FROM (some join)`. You'll also never be able to use the table without quoting it. While it may not be illegal to have a dot in a table name, you're setting yourself and anyone else working on the codebase up for constant confusion, bugs, and hopefully hate in your direction for such a stupid decision.